# How can I select a stable subset of rows from a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I've loaded a file into a DataFrame in Zeppelin notebooks like this:

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("some_file").toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")
```

This DataFrame has >10 million rows, and I would like to start work with just a subset of the rows, so I use limit:

```
val df_small = df.limit(1000)
```

However, now when I try to filter the DataFrame on the string value of one of the columns, I get *different results* every time I run the following:

```
df_small.filter($"c1" LIKE "something").show()
```

How can I take a subset of df that remains stable for every filter I run?

Comment: you should persist or cache the limited dataframe before you apply an action on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark works as a lazy load so only at statement `.show` above 2 statements will execute. you can write `df_small` to a file and read that alone everytime or do `df_small.cache()`